# Tick level data - Skipping values

Tags: python-3.x, database

I just started storing tick level data to use it for my algorithmic strategies and I just noticed there is no continuation in 'exchange_time_stamp', I think it's skipping a few values I guess. can anyone recheck the below data and let me know, is the data normal or is there a problem with it, mainly the 'exchange_time_stamp', is this a connectivity issue

```
quote update {'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 11439, 'ltp': 342.01,'exchange_time_stamp': 1616478841,
              'open': 339.0, 'high': 344.74, 'low': 338.2, 'close': 337.91,
              'yearly_high': 379.79, 'yearly_low': 169.55, 
              'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=11439, symbol='BANKBEES',
                                       name='NIP IND ETF BANK BEES', expiry=None,
                                       lot_size=None)}
quote update {'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 11439, 'ltp': 342.01,'exchange_time_stamp': 1616478843,
              'open': 339.0, 'high': 344.74, 'low': 338.2, 'close': 337.91, 
              'yearly_high': 379.79, 'yearly_low': 169.55, 
              'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=11439, symbol='BANKBEES', 
                                       name='NIP IND ETF BANK BEES', expiry=None,
                                       lot_size=None)}
quote update {'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 11439, 'ltp': 342.08,'exchange_time_stamp': 1616478845,
              'open': 339.0, 'high': 344.74, 'low': 338.2, 'close': 337.91, 
              'yearly_high': 379.79, 'yearly_low': 169.55, 
              'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=11439, symbol='BANKBEES',
                                       name='NIP IND ETF BANK BEES', expiry=None,
                                       lot_size=None)}
quote update {'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 11439, 'ltp': 342.08,'exchange_time_stamp': 1616478846,
              'open': 339.0, 'high': 344.74, 'low': 338.2, 'close': 337.91, 
              'yearly_high': 379.79, 'yearly_low': 169.55, 
              'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=11439, symbol='BANKBEES',
                                       name='NIP IND ETF BANK BEES', expiry=None, 
                                       lot_size=None)}
 quote update {'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 11439, 'ltp': 342.08,'exchange_time_stamp': 1616478848,
              'open': 339.0, 'high': 344.74, 'low': 338.2, 'close': 337.91,
              'yearly_high': 379.79, 'yearly_low': 169.55,
              'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=11439, symbol='BANKBEES',
                                       name='NIP IND ETF BANK BEES', expiry=None, 
                                       lot_size=None)}
 quote update {'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 11439, 'ltp': 342.08,'exchange_time_stamp': 1616478849,
              'open': 339.0, 'high': 344.74, 'low': 338.2, 'close': 337.91,
              'yearly_high': 379.79, 'yearly_low': 169.55,
              'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=11439, symbol='BANKBEES',
                                        name='NIP IND ETF BANK BEES', expiry=None,
                                        lot_size=None)}
 quote update {'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 11439, 'ltp': 342.08,'exchange_time_stamp': 1616478851,
              'open': 339.0, 'high': 344.74, 'low': 338.2, 'close': 337.91,
              'yearly_high': 379.79, 'yearly_low': 169.55, 
              'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=11439, symbol='BANKBEES',
                                       name='NIP IND ETF BANK BEES', expiry=None, 
                                       lot_size=None)}
 quote update {'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 11439, 'ltp': 342.01,'exchange_time_stamp': 1616478852,
              'open': 339.0, 'high': 344.74, 'low': 338.2, 'close': 337.91,
              'yearly_high': 379.79, 'yearly_low': 169.55,
             'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=11439, symbol='BANKBEES',
                                      name='NIP IND ETF BANK BEES', expiry=None,
                                      lot_size=None)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this is from WebSocket data. In WebSocket, you will get an update to your tick when there's a change in the tick values(price, volume etc).

So in practice, a decent WebSocket should provide you at least 1 tick/second, unless you are dealing with illiquid stocks.

But this is not a connectivity issue.